# How to create a FrozenDictionary from a static list

Tags: c#, .net-8.0

An ordinary dictionary can be create from a static list like this:

```
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string> {{1, "Hello" }};
```

The following does not work for a FrozenDictionary, since this class is abstract:

```
    //var frozen = new FrozenDictionary<int, string> {{1, "Hello" }};
```

Here is a possiblility which is much longer and requires more heap allocations:

```
    var array = new KeyValuePair<int, string>[]{ new (1, "Hello" )};
    var frozen = array.ToFrozenDictionary();
```

Obvisouly this is possible as well but constructs the dictionary twice:

```
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string> {{1, "Hello" }};
    var frozen2 = dictionary.ToFrozenDictionary();
```

Is there a better way to create a FrozenDictionary from a static list?

Comment: I don't believe so, the [`ToFrozenDictionary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.frozen.frozendictionary.tofrozendictionary) methods are the entry point to the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`FrozenDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.frozen.frozendictionary-2?view=net-8.0) is an abstract class and has internal implementations so it can't be constructed via collection expressions as ordinary `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. This approach allows to have different specialized/optimized implementations like `Int32FrozenDictionary<TValue> : FrozenDictionary<int, TValue>` or `SmallFrozenDictionary<TKey, TValue>` or series of different `OrdinalStringFrozenDictionary<TValue> : FrozenDictionary<string, TValue>`

Currently it can be instantiated only via framework-provided set of [`FrozenDictionary.ToFrozenDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.frozen.frozendictionary.tofrozendictionary?view=net-8.0) methods as far as I can see.

> Here is a possiblility which is much longer

Obviously it does not actually require separate variable to source collection, you can inline it `var frozen = new KeyValuePair<int, string>[]{ new (1, "Hello" )}.ToFrozenDictionary();`

Also you can create your own version which accepts a collection of value tuples:

```
public static class Exts
{
    public static FrozenDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToFrozenDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<(TKey, TValue)> source) where TKey : notnull
        => source.ToFrozenDictionary(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2);
}
```

Which can simplify usage a bit more:

```
var frozenDictionary = new[] { (1, "Hello" ) }.ToFrozenDictionary();
```

> and requires more heap allocations:

Arguably it should not bother you that much. If you are constantly creating frozen dictionaries in your app critical paths - highly likely you are using frozen dictionary wrong. Usual pattern for this collection is either some static data loaded once per app lifetime (like in the framework itself - [example 1](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/429bd8b709055e6aa867765d1beb577bc28a85be/src/Middleware/OutputCaching/src/OutputCacheEntryFormatter.cs#L509), [example 2](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/429bd8b709055e6aa867765d1beb577bc28a85be/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/HostingMetrics.cs#L134)) or long-lived collections (like cache). If extra allocations are for some reasons still an issue - consider using pooling (for example with framework-provided [`ArrayPool<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=net-8.0) or [`ObjectPool<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.objectpool.objectpool-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)).